# Passing Dates to VBA UDF, returns NUM error

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

The following VBA code works well if it is run as a Sub(), but when it is run as a UDF, I get a #NUM! error.

I as suspecting that there is some problem while passing values to it.

```
Public Function ServiceTaxInterest(PaymentDate As Date, DueDate As Date, TaxAmount As Integer) As Integer

Dim Interest As Double

Interest = 1E-32


If DueDate > PaymentDate Then

    Interest = 0

ElseIf TaxAmount <= 0 Then

    Interest = 0

Else

    For To_day = DueDate To PaymentDate

        If To_day < DateSerial(2014, 10, 1) Then

            Interest = Interest + (TaxAmount * 0.18 / DaysInYear(To_day))

        ElseIf MonthsDelay(DueDate, To_day) < 6 Then

            Interest = Interest + (TaxAmount * 0.18 / DaysInYear(To_day))

        ElseIf MonthsDelay(DueDate, To_day) < 12 Then

            Interest = Interest + (TaxAmount * 0.24 / DaysInYear(To_day))

        Else

            Interest = Interest + (TaxAmount * 0.3 / DaysInYear(To_day))

        End If

    Next

End If

ServiceTaxInterest = Round(Interest, 0)

End Function
```

'

```
Public Function MonthsDelay(StartDate, EndDate) As Integer

    If DateValue(StartDate) > DateValue(EndDate) Then

        i = 0

    ElseIf Day(EndDate) >= Day(StartDate) Then

        i = ((Year(EndDate) - Year(StartDate)) * 12) + (Month(EndDate) - Month(StartDate))

    Else

        i = ((Year(EndDate) - Year(StartDate)) * 12) + (Month(EndDate) - Month(StartDate)) - 1

    End If

MonthsDelay = i

End Function
```

'

```
Public Function DaysInYear(x) As Integer

    If Int(Year(x) / 4) = Year(x) / 4 Then

        DaysInYear = 366

    Else

        DaysInYear = 365

    End If

End Function
```

Please help in identifying the mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code works correctly as a UDF (or at least produces a number and no error) for me, without modification.

I believe the error, as you suspect, is in what you're passing as parameters to the function.

What your UDF needs is something that Excel can evaluate as a number. If you have values in cells that are formatted as dates, you can pass the reference to the cell. If the date in the cell is text (for example, copied from an outside source), you can pass the DATEVALUE(text) function.

My guess is you're most likely manually typing in something like 3/25/2015 into the parameter. Excel will actually read this as a very small number (with the slashes as division) and interpret it as the completely wrong date. Simply passing "3/25/2015" with the quotes will fix that. Excel's Date object recognizes that string as a date and converts it to a value correctly.

Edit: Even safer than enclosing it in quotes, where there may be localization issues (my American-ness is showing with the month/day/year format), you can use the DATE(year,month,day) function as your input instead. Referencing a cell that's formatted as a date is safe too, as the date is just a number that's independent of how Excel is formatting it for you (yyyy/mm/dd, dd/mm/yyyy, etc.))

Comment: Actually I don't do either. I give references to cells which contain dates.

Comment: Is there a way to step into the line by line evaluation of a UDF?

Comment: Yes, in the VBA editor, left click the grey space immediately to the left of a line (can't be a declaration), and it will place a breakpoint. When you type the UDF in a cell and hit enter, it will break there, and you can hover the mouse over variable names to see what they are. I'd suggest putting a breakpoint on the first if statement, and seeing what's coming in as DueDate and PaymentDate. My working inputs were 3/25/2015, 3/4/2015, and 500, which returned 5.

Comment: Hi, I solved the issue. The problem was not with the dates, it was with the TaxAmount. Instead of Integer, I tried it as a Double and it worked as expected. Sorry for the trouble. I was sure that the cell containing the TaxAmount was an integer.